# jQuery JSONP request timeout on second request

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I am developing a mobile application that fetches JSON from the server. Up until recently everything was working perfectly but after my massive refactor im struggling to get my getJSON requests working properly.

When I navigate from my Categories page to my listings page I call this this method:

```
/**
 * This will fetch us the details of a particular listing
 * @param int listingId - The listings ID
 * @param function callback - Will be called on success with the JSON
 */
getListingInfo : function(listingId, callback) {
     $.getJSON(baseUrl+'info?callback=?',{uid:uuid,listingId: listingId}, callback);
},
```

Which works perfectly the first time I click through but on subsequent requests it seems to timeout, even with a different listingId.

I tried using $.ajax instead but have the same problem. When I go into jQuerys core I can log the fully qualified request (where the callback placeholder has been replaced etc) and the request all look correct.

The first time I call it the load time is about 2 seconds but but after that it just hangs. I have had a look at the logs on the server and the second request is not coming through.

Another strange thing is that it works perfectly on my friends HTC desire running a custom ROM but not on my HTC Desire running Android 2.2.2

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and JQM 1.1rc1 ( I have tried jQuery 1.6.4 with no difference )

Im really not too sure where to look any more, any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What is interesting is that I can open the URL in my browser and get prompted to download a binary file, whereas his phone says unsupported content type. The header is application/json